# What's the experience to share a SharePoint site to external guest

Tags: external-users, external-sharing

Sorry for a new question. The security policy mentioned in Microsoft site is too complex to me. I am not sure I am doing the correct setup.

We have a SharePoint online site collection. It is a communication site. I need to share this site to external members. Some of them have 365 license while some do not.

As far as I understanding, both group of users can access our site. However the user without license will have readonly access to the site. Is it true?

Also, as a test, I open site permission -> add my personal account (my personal email box @gmail.com & @yahoo.com) to the "XXX site member group" but nothing is happened. After I pressed "Share" button no email is received and my name is not listed in the group member list.

Am I doing the right procedure to share site?

Answer (score 0):

External guests do not need a Microsoft 365 licence to collaborate (read/write) on your SharePoint site.

You'll need to make sure that your site has external sharing enabled. You can do this by going to SharePoint Admin Center, selecting the site you want to share and select "Sharing". You'll also need to ensure you choose the correct external sharing setting for what you need to do e.g. share the site with a new guest.

[image]

Once external sharing is enabled for the site, you can invite guests from the site itself. Go to the site > Cog > Site permissions > Add members

Comment: After some trial, I found I can send our invitation by using "Share" button. It will not work by adding member in Site permission page. I am not sure why.

Comment: If it's a group connected site, you cannot invite external users to the Microsoft 365 group from within SharePoint (you have to do this from Outlook/Azure AD) but you should be able to give them direct permissions to the site. The old site permissions page usually determines they're external and then you can send an invitation.

Comment: If this answer helped, please do remember to upvote or mark the answer as accepted to help inform the community.

Comment: What do you mean by "The old site permissions page usually determines they're external and then you can send an invitation."? Is there another page to let someone approve the new users are accepted external guest?

Comment: My site is a communication site, not a team site. The groups are SP groups not 365 groups. I have tried  site > Cog > Site permissions > Add members. But nothing have changed. No invitation and no new members.

I think Microsoft have changed the code so the behaviour is different from their official articles... it is really confuse

Comment: You don't approve external users, you just invite them. You can use the classic permissions page by going to the site > Cog > Site permissions > Advanced permissions settings. This page hasn't really changed much. I typically use this classic page for inviting external users directly to a SharePoint site (when using the SharePoint UI).

Comment: In the Advanced permission setting, I press New and input the guest email. Then it shows xxxx@hotmail.com is outside of your organization. Also, the check box "Send an email invitation" become checked but grey out. When I press "Share" the screen disappear and refresh. But nothing happened.

Comment: Yes, this is normal. The user account won't appear in the group until the user has accepted their email invitation and logged in to SharePoint.